# Synchronize OS with virtualized copy on USB pen-drive

Tags: boot, usb

I'm looking to any good solution to:

1. Have Ubuntu installed on a USB-drive
2. Make that Ubuntu a clone of the Ubuntu installed on my laptop
3. Perform incremental synchronization from my laptop OS to the one on the USB (not only data but also software installed, configs, etc...)
4. Run the Ubuntu from the USB on a Windows PC without rebooting (LinuxUSB Creator?), or alternatively by rebooting.

I saw some posts about almost each of those points, but I couldn't understand if all of them can be achieved.

Thanks! F.

Comment: I think all points except #3 are straight-forward, if you avoid proprietary drivers (to keep it portable) and accept rebooting of the Windows computer. Maybe it will be difficult to get *incremental* synchronization  including software installed etc.

Comment: yes I knew that by reading at other topics... Actually have the sync is what really does the difference :(   thanks for your comment

Comment: Maybe it will work except for the bootloader, if you synchronize with `unison`, when booted from 'a third' drive. But the bootloader need not change often. Maybe it will work better with permissions and ownership with `rsync`, but you must make `rsync` delete files in the target, when the corresponding files are deleted in the source. -  A simpler alternative would be to allow the operating systems to differ, and to have separate **data partitions, that are synchronized**, for example with `unison`.